# How to check if a database exists in Hsqldb/Derby?

Tags: derby, hsqldb

I am looking for information how to check if a database exists -- from Java code -- in hsqldb and in Apache derby. In Mysql it is quite easy, because I can query a system table -- `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA` -- but these two databases seem not to have such a table.

What is an alternative to mysql query:

```
 SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = <DATABASE NAME>
```

to find if a database exists in hsqldb and apache derby?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437765/javadb-checking-if-a-database-exists

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Checking if a Database exists

One solution is to append ";ifexists=true" to the database URL and try opening the database in this way. If the database doesn't exist, you will get an exception. This works for and HSQLDB and the H2 database. For Apache Derby, append ";create=false" (actually, just make sure there is no ";create=true"). The ";create=false" also works for the H2 database, but not for HSQLDB (it's simply ignored there). The disadvantage of this ";ifexists=true" / ";create=false" trick is: you would be using exception handling for application flow control, which should be avoided (not only because throwing exceptions is slow). Also, you would open a connection which you may not want. Update: HSQLDB 2.x seems to print the stack trace to System.err(!) if the database doesn't exists and you use ";ifexists=true", in addition to throwing an exception.

You could check if the database file(s) exist(s). The disadvantage is this depends on how the database URL is mapped to a file name, which depends on database internals such as the database type and database version(!), and maybe on system properties. For Derby, you need to check if the directory exists, and additionally for some file, such as "service.properties" (it seems). For HSQLDB, you could check if the file databaseName.properties exists. For H2, check for the file databaseName.h2.db. That's with current versions of Derby / HSQLDB / H2, and may change in the future.

The question is, of course: why do you need to know if the database already exists?

### Checking if a Schema exists

Maybe you don't actually want to check if a *database* exists. Instead, you only want to check if the given *schema* exists within the database. For that, you can use

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = '<SCHEMA NAME>'
```

This works for both HSQLDB (since version 2.x) and H2. It also works with other databases. One exception is Derby, which doesn't support the standardized INFORMATION_SCHEMA schema.

Comment: I have an implementation of a specialized client -- create complex db schema etc. -- for mysql and I would like to have a junit that uses local derby or hsqldb for running tests. In my mysql client I use SCHEMATA to find out if a database or a table exists. So I have to change the implementation to have my code portable to hsqldb.

Comment: So, is the concensus to do this:  check if derby db file exists using File.class and if not, then create connection with the create=true argument , otherwise use create=false argument?

Comment: @djangofan I think you can also use create=true if the database already exists (in that case it's a no-op). But I suggest to read the Derby documentation, as I'm not very familiar with Derby.

Comment: @Mueller - I was "guessing" the same thing but couldn't find it anywhere in the documentation.  Link anyone?

Comment: @ThomasMueller How can I check If user I created is exist in HSQLDB

Answer (score 1):

For HSQLDB 2.0 (use the latest snapshot for better compatibility with MySQL) you don't have to change much, as long as your database / schema is not called 'PUBLIC'.

Connecting to the test database, which can be an all-in-memory database will create an empty database by default (which contains the PUBLIC schema). After this use

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'DATABASE NAME'
```

Note that the name should be in single quotes. I don't know if MySQL accepts the name in single quotes or not.

If the schema does not exist, then run your schema creation code, as you would with MySQL.

Comment: How can I check if user exist in HSQLDB

Comment: The INFORMATION_SCHEMA.AUTHORIZATIONS table contains the user names.

Comment: I mean, can I check like CREATE USER if not exists

Comment: Read the Guide. IF NOT EXISTS is not supported for CREATE USER.

Answer (score 0):

Since Derby databases are essentially directories with the name of the database acting as the name of the directory, you can instead check to see if that directory exists by supplying the path to the directory:

```
if (Files.isDirectory(Paths.get("employees"))) {
    System.out.println("Database already exists");
}
else {
    // Code to create database
}
```

In my example I'm checking for a database named "employees," which is embedded in my project sructure. You could supply the absolute path to your database or a relative path.