# Create .exe for java swing app with embedded HSQL

Tags: java, exe, hsqldb

Recently I made an application in using Swing, HSQL Embedded that manages some database. I used HSQL as the backend to connect to the database. What I want to do is create a setup/installer program so that the application can be installed and used on any pc. My problem is I dont know how to integrate the database along?

Comment: What do you mean by "integrate"? Specify.

Comment: make an exe file that install on any pc..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [exe4j](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/exe4j/overview.html) to generate .exe.

And [wizard4j](http://wizard4j.org/) to create installer for your application.

Comment: I haven't test that, but you can try :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that creation of exe is quite isolated case. In case of Windows, you will create `msi` package, in case of OSX, you will create `dmg`, in case of Linux, you will create `rpm` or `tar.gz` etc. Yes you could use `exe4j`, install4j etc. But I strongly recommend to put your `jar` in one specific folder, `zip` it and distribute in that format.
Now, when it comes to your database "integration", have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801773/how-to-check-if-a-database-exists-in-hsqldb-derby) and [this documentation](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/databaseobjects-chapt.html). Reason for distributing Java application this way and not with installer come from bad experiences I encountered when writing data into flat file databases after applications get installed via `install4j` or `exe4j`.